# Intuition: groups, quotient groups, cosets, homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition

If we start with the group of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$
and the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$; $\mathbb{Z}$ the integers,
and then form the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}$
we have that this quotient group consists
of all the cosets of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

These are of the form $a + \mathbb{Z}$, $a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

E.g. $...\frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{8}{3}...$ 
i.e. the coset $\frac{2}{3} + \mathbb{Z}$.

These cosets are the elements of the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}$ and is a partiton of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then we have that $\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}$
is homomorphic to the circle $S^1$.

$\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z} \:\cong \:S^1$

This is because the cosets 
are parameterized by elements belonging to
the interval $[0,1]$. Every coset has 
exactly one element in it (as long as
we make the identification that $0 = 1$, because
it belongs to the original subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$)

$\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}\: \cong \:S^1$ ($\cong [0,1]$ with $0=1$)

I think these things are rather difficult and
i wonder if my intuition, understanding,
of them and the connection between them are ok, or
if there are some flaws?

---

Clarification from the discussion in the comments:
The statement $\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z}\: \cong \:S^1$
comes from Wildberger's video lectures and what he probably 
means is that these are homeomorphic as spaces.
But even this is wrong.

Conclusion: Do not watch his videos :)

Comment: $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb S^1$. You confuse with $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb  S^1$.

Comment: Usually $S^1$ denotes the unit circle in the real plane, which is far larger than this group.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202243/how-do-i-visualize-cosets-of-a-group

Comment: @Surb I am watching Wildberger's video lectures and he says $\mathbb{Q}$/$\mathbb{Z} \:\cong \:S^1$. I know he is considered as either a genius or nuts...so he is wrong here?

Comment: He says they are homomorphic as spaces.

Comment: What does it even mean to be homomorphic?

Comment: @JKnecht: I don't know him but he probably made a mistakes. You only have that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb S^1$. So $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb S^1$, but not isomorphic to $\mathbb S^1$. In fact, just by simple logical, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is countable whereas $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is not. Therefore, they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Maybe what he meant to say was that they are homeomorphic as spaces...but i guess thats wrong too?

Comment: Yes, it is also clearly false that they are homeomorphic, as one is countable while the other is not. But given the view of Wildberger on anything infinite, who knows?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks, i should probably watch something else instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb S^1$ which is the unit circle. What we have is the following isomorphism with the multiplicative group of roots of unit

$$\begin{align}\varphi: \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z &\to C^{\times}\\\frac{p}{q} + \mathbb Z &\mapsto e^{\frac{2\pi i p}{q}}\end{align}$$

Comment: And its not true that they are _homomorphic_ as _spaces_?

Comment: @JKnecht What does it mean to be homomorphic?

Comment: I think Jknecht want to say *isomorphic*, no ? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Do you mean homeomorphic?

Comment: @Surb That would be odd since he has already been told that this is not the case (and makes the "as spaces" odd too).

Comment: @AaronMaroja Yes, i guess he meant homeomorphic as spaces...but thats make no sense either?

Comment: It doesn't. Because one is countable and $\mathbb S^1$ isn't. What I posted holds true though, which is the closest you can get from what you are thinking, I suppose.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys...i will stop watching that guy. @TobiasKildetoft Surb AaronMaroja